# onEdit range always cell A1

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I've run into an issue with the `onEdit` [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers#Simple) using the [Google Apps Script] [3](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/) in a Google Doc Spreadsheet.

The `range` in the [`event object`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events#eventsDetails) passed to `onEdit` always maps back to cell `A1`.
There are a few other issues I'm encountering with `onEdit` and the `event object` but this is a very narrow and specific example which is hopefully easy to ask a question about.

My Repro Steps:

1. Login to google docs
2. Create new spreadsheet
3. `Tools->Script Editor` (this will open in a new tab)
4. Replace contents of Code.gs with the following (C&P from [https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events#eventsDetails])

```
function onEdit(e) {  
    e.range.setComment("Edited at: " + new Date().toTimeString());   
}
```

5. Save changes to Code.gs
6. Return to the spreadsheet tab
7. Enter the number 7 into cell `C3` then hit enter
   Note: What's entered doesn't appear to matter, just need to trigger the `onEdit` event
8. Wait for spreadsheet to save change to server
9. Cell `A1` is updated with a comment that says, `Edited at: [current time]`

The expected behavior is that the comment is added to cell C3. As per the [documentation stating] [2](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events#eventsDetails);

> [The example in step 4] is a function that is triggered when a
> Spreadsheet is edited. It uses the e parameter to access the cell that
> was edited and add a timestamp.

Having this basic example from documentation failing leaves me at a loss of what I can be doing incorrectly or how else to approach finding a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the release of new sheets, a few of the Google Apps Script features where broken, in particular the one that you mention.

You will find documentation on this and other current issues here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/migration/sheets#onedit_triggers

Be sure that the team is working hard to resolve this and you can probably have a shot as asking a question or two on the subject in wednesday Google Apps Unscripted : https://plus.google.com/u/0/116174873209306927411/posts/MbXQhKusUZ3?cfem=1